# struts.xml namespace causes 404 not found page

Tags: java, xml, struts2, namespaces, actionresult

I have the problem on `struts.xml` of Struts 2 web project.
I have the login page and after login, the URL will add `/secure/*.action`.

I tried to have two packages in `struts.xml`. One is normal `/` and second is `/secure`. But it will cause 404 not found page after login. If I make the second package also `\` in namespace and call the `membersite.action` with only `/` namespace , it will be OK and successfully direct but with only `/*.action` in URL. I need to have this URL `/secure/*.action` in infrastructure issue. Is there any hints?

```
    <package name="awip" namespace="/" extends="tiles-default, struts-default">
    <result-types>
      <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult"/>
    </result-types>
    <global-results>
        <result name="sessionTimeout"   type="tiles">.logon.LogonForm</result>      
        <result name="errorRedirect"    type="tiles">.errorPage</result>        
    </global-results>
    <action name="logon" class="logonAction" method="displayLogonForm">
        <result name="displayLogonForm" type="tiles">.logon.LogonForm</result>
    </action>
    <action name="doLogon" class="logonAction" method="doLogon">
        <result name="displayLogonForm" type="tiles">.logon.LogonForm</result>
        <result name="displayMainPage"              type="redirectAction">
            <param name="namespace">/secure</param> 
            <param name="actionName">membersite.action</param>
        </result>
    </action>
</package>
<package name="secureAwip" namespace="/secure" extends="tiles-default, struts-default">
    <result-types>
      <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult"/>
    </result-types>
    <global-results>
        <result name="sessionTimeout"   type="tiles">.logon.LogonForm</result>      
        <result name="errorRedirect"    type="tiles">.errorPage</result>        
    </global-results>
    <action name="membersite" method="unspecified" class="membersiteAction">
        <result name="displayMembersiteMain" type="tiles">.membersite.Main
        </result>
    </action>
 </package>
```

Answer (score 0):

The action name should not have an extension `.action`. If you write it with the action name the action mapper can't find the appropriate mapping for the action's result.

The code

```
<param name="actionName">membersite.action</param>
```

should be changed to

```
<param name="actionName">membersite</param>
```

Comment: I have found the problem. As I have the loginFilter which will check the session userID value. If it is null, it will show the problem. As I have crossed the namespace, session userID will become null. I cannot remove the login Filter, is there any way to solve it??

Comment: What is the loginFilter?

Comment: It is the custom made java filter that will apply for every page in the contextroot url. Like the include file in the php for every page.

Comment: Is there any features in struts2 to preserve the session in redirectAction of changing namespace? .e.g add <param name="preserveSession"> true</param>

Comment: The problem is in your loginFilter, not in struts2, if it changes the session several times it won't keep any data in session.